# cmake can't find the depending library

Tags: cmake

I have a demo project which rely on a logger library, The file structure of the relevant files are listed as below:

```
.
├── FancyLogger
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── FancyLogger.cpp
│   ├── FancyLogger.h
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── libFancyLogger.a
└── HelloClion
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── helloclion.cpp
```

I have build a static library named as `libFancyLogger.a` in the `./FancyLogger/bin` directory.

My CMakeFiles of the project `HelloClion` is listed as below:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(HelloClion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

```
get_filename_component(CODE_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DIRECTORY)

set(SOURCE_FILES helloclion.cpp)

add_executable(HelloClion ${SOURCE_FILES})
include_directories(${CODE_ROOT}/FancyLogger)
link_directories(${CODE_ROOT}/FancyLogger/bin)
target_link_libraries(HelloClion FancyLogger)
```

But the linker complains that `library not found for -lFancyLogger`, I don't know how to fix this, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seems to find out why. ;)

In the cmake documentation:https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html

> link_directories(directory1 directory2 ...)
>
> Specify the paths in which
>   the linker should search for libraries. The command will apply only to
>   targets created after it is called.

The doc says, the command only applys to targets created after it is called. So I just need to move `link_directories(${CODE_ROOT}/FancyLogger/bin)` to some position in front of the `add_executable(HelloClion ${SOURCE_FILES})` command.

Problems solved!